# Lato Font not rendering in IE but its working fine in Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am using Google Lato font for my UI Development perspective but i had a problem when i using lato font it doesn't render correctly in IE but its working fine in Chrome Browser, I couldn't understand what happened?

I just download the Google font to my local

**Lato Google Font**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

**My Local Path**
[image]

**Specify in CSS**

```
body {    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;}
```

**Chrome** - Its Taking `'Lato'`

**IE** - Lato Font Not Rendering, Instead of lato font it will take `sans-serif`

I don't know what i missed, can you help me in that case ?

Comment: IE Version 11 @Rahul

Comment: @RaviDelixan update your post with that information - it's important data that should be immediately obvious in the question =) Also as per Yoav's answer, you're showing CSS that is tailored for Chrome, so that doesn't tell us anything. Open the IE11 dev tools (F12) and then find the CSS code that it tries to load, and update the post with that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google loads the relevant webfont file according to the client browser.
Chrome aupports woff2 while IE supports woff.
If you will load the same css through explorer you'll get woff files in the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks @yoav Sharia, its working fine for me as per your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I used google font lato via

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it renders properly on IE11 (on windows) as well as chrome , so I suggest try to used google font from google api instead of downloading it on ur local machine or ur server

also check out this link [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) this might help you